# phoenix authenticate current_user

Tags: authentication, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to write a small application to Phoenix. I did authentication by example http://meatherly.github.io/2015/05/11/phoenixauthentication/

I think everything turned out, but I can not figure out how to work with the data of the current_user.
If I write in controller:

```
user = conn.assigns.current_user
IO.inspect user
```

I get:

```
{:ok,
 %Myfiles.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">,
  encrypted_password: "$2b$12$KLDREZ08084BhHXrJR8EAuQinHn.X2X9OlfylelYiK5KSinlxfTii",
  id: 1, inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-10-07 21:28:51>, password: "123456",
  password_confirmation: "123456",
  updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-10-07 21:28:51>, username: "test"}}
```

this is not a map? how to get out of here id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `current_user` is a tuple that containing `:ok` and a `user` struct.You can get id out like this:

```
{:ok, user} = conn.assigns.current_user
IO.inspect user.id
```

You can read more about struct [here](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/structs.html)